# CKEditor: Allow video embed code

Tags: video, embed, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor and want to allow the insertion of embed code from YouTube, Vimeo etc.
CKEditor turns all tags into HTML Chars equivalent, which is good, but I want it to make exceptions for this kind of content. iFrames seem to be how it's done nowadays, so how can I tell CKEditor to leave iFrame tags alone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found your question while searching for the same solution. Here is what I found. Basically, it adds a button to your toolbar like the Image button, but it pops up a box for you to paste the embed code from YouTube, Vimeo etc. into. Seems to work pretty well.

http://www.fluidbyte.net/index.php?view=embed-youtube-vimeo-etc-into-ckeditor

Edit: Link to archive.org:
http://web.archive.org/web/20110805213357/http://www.fluidbyte.net/index.php?view=embed-youtube-vimeo-etc-into-ckeditor

Comment: I was getting Error 400 when I tried to embed. To fix it, I just changed the following code (at line 30) from plugin.js `'<iframe src="'+me.path+'/dialogs/mediaembed.html" frameborder="0" name="iframeMediaEmbed" id="iframeMediaEmbed" allowtransparency="1" style="width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe>'` To `html: '<iframe src="' + me.path + 'dialogs/mediaembed.html" frameborder="0" name="iframeMediaEmbed" id="iframeMediaEmbed" allowtransparency="1" style="width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe>'`

Comment: He apparently is moving his blog to Tumblr and will (presumably) be moving his content over soon. In the meantime: http://web.archive.org/web/20110805213357/http://www.fluidbyte.net/index.php?view=embed-youtube-vimeo-etc-into-ckeditor

Answer (score 4):

No.  None of these answers are exactly accurate.  The plugin is overkill for what you want to do.  Do a project wide search for the following text: `extraAllowedContent` and add `'iframe[!src];'` to whatever other allowed content is there.  Then add the following: `allowedContent: true,`

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor comes with a `config.js` file. In this file, set the paramater `config.allowedContent` to `true`.

For example,

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.toolbar_TRiGCustom =
    [
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','-','Blockquote'],
        ['FontSize'],
        ['Undo','Redo'],
        ['Link','Unlink','Image','Table'],
        ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
        ['Source'],
        ['Maximize']
    ];
    config.toolbar = 'TRiGCustom';
    config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
    config.forceSimpleAmpersand = true;
    config.resize_enabled = false;
    config.toolbarCanCollapse = false;
    config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
    config.language = 'en';
    config.uiColor = '#76BC49';
    config.width = '97%';
    config.extraPlugins = 'maximize';
    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

I found this solution on the [Amixa Blog](http://www.amixa.com/blog/2014/09/03/ckeditor-4-2-or-later-will-not-allow-iframe-or-other-html-tags/). The blog post seems to be written for a specific CMS called ASPMAKER, and also recommends tweaks to specific ASP files in that CMS, but this edit to CKEditor config is generic, and applies to CKEditor wherever you're using it. The line `config.allowedContent = true;` is all you need.

Comment: TL;DR - add config.allowedContent = true;

Comment: If you want to disable Advanced Content Filter, set `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent` to `true`. All available editor features will be activated and input data will not be filtered. Note that you cannot use `CKEDITOR.config.disallowedContent` when ACF is disabled.
If you use only `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true`, you will allowed user to do nasty things.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is enabling the 'Source' button. If you use the full toolbar (not basic) it is already present.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the end-user isn't techincal at all and giving him the Source Button could be a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the "Source" button does not solve this problem.  Embed code such as "iframe" can then be pasted, but if you come back and edit the field a second time, CKeditor will have stripped it.  You need to configure CKeditor to allow iframe embedding in the first place.

Comment: "You need to configure CKeditor to allow iframe embedding in the first place." How?