# IE:8 javascript error ... permission denied while embedding utube video in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor 4.1 version. When I select Embed youtube video from toolbar and enter some url then i get 'permssion denied' js error. 
This works well in chrome and FF but not in ie8.
Please help.

Comment: I think that what you whant is this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221583/ckeditor-allow-video-embed-code

Comment: actually I am able to add youtube videos using youtube plugin in FF and chrome... it's only IE 8.0 where I get 'permission denied' js error. As per my understanding the url shows how to embed videos which I already done except IE 8 issue.